# Dificultad al validar tipos mime en php para subir archivos al servidor

Tags: php, archivo, validación, upload, mime

#### Contextualización del problema

Estoy tratando de hacer una clase en [php](/questions/tagged/php) que permita validar el tipo [mime](/questions/tagged/mime) de los archivos que son subidos al servidor. Su propósito es rechazar los archivos cuyo tipo declarado no coincida con el tipo que se puede identificar en su contenido, y autorizar validaciones de fondo para los demás.
Al revisar la clase [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/es/book.fileinfo.php) que ofrece entre otras cosas la información necesaria para saber los tipos mime de los archivos me encontré con algunas sorpresas que no esperaba:

1. El método [***mime_content_type()***](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mime-content-type.php) que se usaba para identificar el tipo mime de un archivo **fue declarado obsoleto** (aunque todavía es soportado).
2. El tipo mime devuelto los métodos ofrecidos por la clase no corresponde (para algunos tipos de archivo - ignoro cuantos) con las cadenas mime pasada en la estructura que entrega la superglobal $_FILES, bajo el supuesto de que sea correcta.
3. Al consultar los archivos [***mime.types*** oficiales mantenido por *apache.org*](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types), [MDN web docs - Lista completa de tipos MIME](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Lista_completa_de_tipos_MIME) e [*IANA* - Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), para establecer la relación entre extensiones y tipos mime: el primero vincula las extensiones de archivo con los tipos devueltos por la función obsoleta, el segundo esta totalmente desactualizado y el tercero ofrece las referencias (verbosas) de los tipos ligadas con sus documentos de registro público; de modo que un aplicativo simple no puede extraer de allí (sin una cantidad abrumadora de descargas) la información necesaria. Adicionalmente, no he sido capaz de sortear las referencias circulares de los buscadores y no he encontrado una idea significativa en StackExchange ni foros similares.

Como consecuencia de las circunstancias anotadas, no se percibe con claridad un criterio de decisión para establecer cuando es válido el tipo mime declarado por un archivo; a no ser que se construya (y mantenga actualizada) una tabla de equivalencias entre tipos nuevos y tipos "obsoletos" (que por lo dicho arriba no parece tarea a la mano).
Y, aunque es claro que el tipo identificado por el cliente para el archivo puede ser truqueado y no debe ser criterio para aceptarlo, la no coincidencia entre este y el detectado en el servidor si debe ser criterio suficiente para rechazarlo. De modo que verificar que la haya es fundamental.

He construido una primera clase, que debe ser instanciada cuando se desea validar el tipo mime de un archivo que ha sido subido al servidor y se encuentra en la carpeta **tmp** a la espera de que las validaciones den vía a pasarlo a su destino final o que lo rechacen.
Esta clase ofrece tres métodos públicos isValid(), getErrMessages(), tipoMime() sus nombres son autoexplicativos. Y, temporalmente un método para lanzar depuraciones al que llamo isValidTest() dispuesto para ensayar cualquier cosa que parezca razonable, pero devolviendo la misma salida que produciría isValid()

Mi problema, se centra en que de momento el método isValid($fileinfo) **no puede ofrecer una salida confiable** dadas las limitaciones indicadas arriba para identificar el tipo mime del archivo en verificación. A continuación posteo el código de la clase:

#### Código en proceso de validación

```
<?php
/**
 * @Filename: /module/Biblio2ls/src/Library/Uploader/fileMimeValidator.php
 *
 *  uso:
 *      use \Biblio2ls\Library\Uploader\fileMimeValidator
 *      $validador = new fileMimeValidator();
 */

namespace Biblio2ls\Library\Uploader;
define('UPLOAD_ERR_FORMATO_INCORRECTO', 9);
define('UPLOAD_ERR_ARCHIVO_ILEGIBLE', 11);
define('UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION_MULTIPLE', 12);
define('UPLOAD_ERR_ATAQUE', 13);
define('UPLOAD_ERR_SIN_EXTENSION', 14);

/**
 * Utilitario para validar tipos mime de los archivos cargados al servidor antes 
 * de moverlos a sus destinos finales.
 *
 * @author Luis Guillermo Quevedo
 */
class fileMimeValidator {
    protected $ext_tipe = [];
    protected $file_mime = [];
    protected $err_info = [];
    protected $mimesconstraint = [];
    protected $restricted = FALSE;

    public function __construct($custom_constraint=[]){
        $this->mimesconstraint = is_array($custom_constraint) ? $custom_constraint : [];
        $this->restricted = (count($this->mimesconstraint) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $tipos = variable_get('tipos_mime', NULL);
        $this->ext_tipe = ($tipos) ? $tipos : $this->tiposMimeReadPrepare();
    }

    protected function addFileMimeInfo($info, $key = ''){
        if($key){
            $this->file_mime[$key] = $info;
        } else {
            if(!in_array($info, $this->file_mime)){ $this->file_mime[] = $info; }
        }        
    }

    protected function detectTipeInMagicfiles($filenm, $mimeoptn = FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE){
        $salida = 0;
        if( !(class_exists('finfo', false)) ) { return $salida; }
        $mimekey = $this->mimeConstantKeys();
        $mimefiles = $this->mimeCommonMagicLocations();
        foreach ($mimefiles as $mf) {
            $finfo = finfo_open($mimeoptn, $mf);
            if($finfo){
                $this->addFileMimeInfo( finfo_file($finfo, $filenm), $mimekey[$mimeoptn] );
                $salida++;
            }
            finfo_close($finfo);
            if($salida){ break; }
        }
        return $salida;
    }

    public function getErrMessages(){ return $this->err_info; }

    public function isValid(&$fileinfo, $custom_constraint=NULL){
        $this->resetValidation($custom_constraint);
        if(!$this->siElFormatoDeEntradaEsValido($fileinfo)){ return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_FORMATO_INCORRECTO); }
        if(!$this->siElArchivoEsLegible($fileinfo['tmp_name'])){ return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_ARCHIVO_ILEGIBLE); }
        if(!$this->siLaExtensionEsAdmisible($fileinfo) ){ return 0; }
        $this->detectTipeInMagicfiles($fileinfo['tmp_name']);
        $this->obsoleteMimeType($fileinfo['tmp_name']);
        $mimeasociadoaextension = (isset($this->ext_tipe[$fileinfo['extension']])) ? $this->ext_tipe[$fileinfo['extension']] : '';
        // Si se pasa un array de restricciones bien establecidas se usa el nuevo modelo
        if($this->restricted){
            // El tipo de campo declarado debe coincidir con el registro de extensiones actualizado y estar en las restricciones impuestas
            return (in_array($this->file_mime['default_mime_type'], $this->mimesconstraint))  ? 1 : $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
        }elseif($fileinfo['type'] === $mimeasociadoaextension){
            // Por ahora parece que la única validación a mano es la obsoleta
            return ($this->file_mime['mime_content_type'] === $mimeasociadoaextension) ? 1 : $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
        }else{
            return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
        }
    }

    public function isValidTest(&$fileinfo, $custom_constraint=NULL){
        $this->resetValidation($custom_constraint);
        if(!$this->siElFormatoDeEntradaEsValido($fileinfo)){ return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_FORMATO_INCORRECTO); }
        if(!$this->siElArchivoEsLegible($fileinfo['tmp_name'])){ return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_ARCHIVO_ILEGIBLE); }
        if(!$this->siLaExtensionEsAdmisible($fileinfo) ){ return 0; }
        $mimekeys = array_keys($this->mimeConstantKeys());
        foreach ($mimekeys as $mimekey){
            $this->detectTipeInMagicfiles($fileinfo['tmp_name'], $mimekey);
        }
        $obsolete_type = $this->obsoleteMimeType($fileinfo['tmp_name']);
        $mimeasociadoaextension = (isset($this->ext_tipe[$fileinfo['extension']])) ? $this->ext_tipe[$fileinfo['extension']] : '';
        $debug = [
            '$this->file_mime'          => $this->file_mime, 
            'tipo declarado en archivo' => $fileinfo['type'], 
            'Mime asociado a extensión' => $mimeasociadoaextension,
            'Mime obsoleto: mime_content_type($filenm)' => $obsolete_type
        ];
        mdf($debug, 'success');
        if($this->restricted){
            // El tipo de campo declarado debe coincidir con el registro de extensiones actualizado y estar en las restricciones impuestas
            // Pero, no se revisa la extensión (falta)
            return (in_array($this->file_mime['default_mime_type'], $this->mimesconstraint))  ? 1 : $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
        }elseif($fileinfo['type'] === $mimeasociadoaextension){
            // Se usa el tipo obsoleto pues no se cuenta aún con algo mejor
            return ($this->file_mime['mime_content_type'] === $mimeasociadoaextension) ? 1 : $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
        }else{
            return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
        }
    }

    protected function mimeCommonMagicLocations(){
        $locations = [
            '/usr/share/misc/magic',
            '/usr/share/misc/magic.mime',
            '/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc',
            '/usr/share/mime/magic',
            '/usr/share/mime/magic.mime',
            '/usr/share/mime/magic.mgc',
            '/usr/share/file/magic',
            '/usr/share/file/magic.mime',
            '/usr/share/file/magic.mgc'
        ];
        return $locations;
    }

    protected function mimeConstantKeys(){
        $mimekeys = [
            FILEINFO_NONE     => 'FILEINFO_NONE',     FILEINFO_SYMLINK        => 'FILEINFO_SYMLINK', 
            FILEINFO_DEVICES  => 'FILEINFO_DEVICES',  FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE      => 'FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE',
            FILEINFO_CONTINUE => 'FILEINFO_CONTINUE', FILEINFO_PRESERVE_ATIME => 'FILEINFO_PRESERVE_ATIME', 
            FILEINFO_RAW      => 'FILEINFO_RAW',      FILEINFO_MIME_ENCODING  => 'FILEINFO_MIME_ENCODING', 
            FILEINFO_MIME     => 'FILEINFO_MIME'
        ];
        return $mimekeys;
    }

    /**
     * los tipos devueltos por finfo_file() y mime_content_type() no
     * coinciden para algunas tipos de archivo (particularmente imágenes validas
     * y, el tipo asociado en $_FILES suele ser el devuelto por mime_content_type()
     * @param type $filenm path del archivo a verificar
     */
    protected function obsoleteMimeType($filenm){
        // Pasa primero el tipo registrado en la BD del servidor (apache)
        $finfo = finfo_open();
        $defaultmime = finfo_file($finfo, $filenm);
        $this->addFileMimeInfo($defaultmime, 'default_mime_type');
        finfo_close($finfo);
        /**
         * Problema: los tipos devueltos por finfo_file() y mime_content_type() no
         * coinciden para algunas imágenes validas
         */
        $salida = mime_content_type($filenm);
        $this->addFileMimeInfo( $salida, 'mime_content_type' );
        return $salida;
    }

    protected function resetValidation($custom_constraint=NULL){
        $this->file_mime = [];
        $this->err_info = []; 
        if(is_array($custom_constraint)){
            $this->mimesconstraint = is_array($custom_constraint) ? $custom_constraint : [];
            $this->restricted = (count($this->mimesconstraint) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        }
    }

    protected function setTipoMimeError(&$fileinfo, $errorcode){
        $fileinfo['error'] = $errorcode;
        switch ($errorcode) {
          case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
              $this->err_info['Tipo mime incorrecto'] = 'La extensión no corresponde al tipo mime declarado';
              break;
          case UPLOAD_ERR_FORMATO_INCORRECTO:
              $this->err_info['formato inadecuado'] = 'La información de archivo debe ser un array con la estructura típica de $_FILES';
              break;            
          case UPLOAD_ERR_ARCHIVO_ILEGIBLE:
              $this->err_info['no es legible'] = "El archivo no se puede leer o no existe.";
              break;
          case UPLOAD_ERR_ATAQUE:
              $this->err_info['detectado ataque'] = "Intento de alterar el sistema de directorios.";
              break;
          case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION_MULTIPLE:
              $this->err_info['posible ataque'] = "Intento de subir archivo con extensión múltiple. Podría estar disfrazado.";
              break;
          case UPLOAD_ERR_SIN_EXTENSION:
              $this->err_info['archivo no admitido'] = "El archivo no es admitido. No tiene tipo explícito.";
              break;      
          default:
        break;
        }
        return ($errorcode > 0) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    protected function siElArchivoEsLegible($file){
        if (empty($file) || false === stream_resolve_include_path($file)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    protected function siElFormatoDeEntradaEsValido($fileinfo){
        if (!isset($fileinfo['tmp_name']) || !isset($fileinfo['name']) || !isset($fileinfo['type'])) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    protected function siLaExtensionEsAdmisible(&$fileinfo){
        $filenm = trim($fileinfo['name']);
        if($filenm == ''){ return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_ARCHIVO_ILEGIBLE); } 
        if( (substr($filenm, 0, 1) == '.') || (strpos($filenm, '..') > 0) ){ return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_ATAQUE); }
        $chunk = explode('.', $filenm);
        if(count($chunk) > 2){
            return $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION_MULTIPLE);
        }else{
            $fileinfo['extension'] = $chunk[1];
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public function tipoMime(){ return isset($this->file_mime['mime_content_type']) ? $this->file_mime['mime_content_type'] : '';  }

    protected function tiposMimeReadPrepare(){
        $salida = []; $duplicados=[];
        $lectura = leer_archivo_de_texto_auxiliar('includes/mimeinfo/mime.types', 'Biblio2ls');
        if(!($lectura)){ return $salida; }
        preg_match_all('#^([^\s]{2,}?)\s+(.+?)$#ism', $lectura, $lineas, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach($lineas as $linea){
            $exts = split(" ", $linea[2]);
            foreach ($exts as $ext){
                if(isset($salida[$ext])){ $duplicados[] = [$ext => $salida[$ext]]; }
                $salida[$ext] = $linea[1];
            }
        }
        if(count($salida)>0){
            ksort($salida);
            variable_set('tipos_mime', $salida);
        }
        if(count($duplicados)>0){
            variable_set('tipos_mime_duplicados', $duplicados);
        }else{
            variable_del('tipos_mime_duplicados');
        }
        return $salida;
    }
}
```

En esta clase hay 5 llamados a métodos del espacio de nombres que no pueden ser ejecutados si el código es copiado y ejecutado paso a documentarlos para facilitar su emulación:

```
<?php
// Se presume que existe el la BD "del sitio" una tabla para registro de
// parámetros de entorno que deben ser fácilmente accesables por los 
// módulos de código. Y que esa tabla tiene dos columnas una tipo chr*255
// (clave primaria) y otra bigtext serializada en la que se guardan los
// valores de las variables. Esa tabla es controlada mediante una entidad
// estática que extiende el abstractor de conexiones a bd y se definen
// tres métodos alias en el espacio de nombres global para hacerla  
// disponible en todas partes
function  variable_get($nombre_variable, $default_si_no_definida){ 
   // lógica para leer en tabla variables el registro con
   // id = $nombrevariable y devolver unserialize(valor_en_columna_valor)
}
function  variable_set($nombre_variable, $valor){ 
   // lógica para guardar en tabla variables el registro con
   // id = $nombrevariable y valor = serialize($valor)
}
function  variable_del($nombre_variable){ 
   // lógica para borrar en tabla variables el registro con
   // id = $nombrevariable en caso de que exista o seguir derecho
   // en silencio si no se encuentra
}

/**
 * Hace un dump bonito!
 * el llamado mdf($msg_obj, $context) es un equivalente a dump, que
 * pasa los M ensajes de  D epuración con  F ormato usando
 * los contextos y clases (twitter-bootstrap) para qe se presenten 
 * amables y ordenados sin afectar la estructura de la página que se
 * está depurando.
 * Se puede reemplazar por dump($msg_obj); sin pérdida. 
 * @param mixed $msg_obj  cualquier objeto que se quiera mostrar
 * @param string $context info|prymary|succes|danger|warning|default| NULL
 * @param boolean $timed 1|0 hora con minutos, segundos y timestamp
 */
function mdf($msg_obj, $context=NULL, $timed=0){
   // lógica para hacer un dump bonito
    dump($msg_obj);
}

/**
 * Es un equivalente de file_get_contents($file)
 * que resuelve los paths y valida su existencia para evitar la carga
 * innecesaria de archivos hecha por el autoload de zendframework
 * para casos de archivos que en general no son requeridos pero que
 * eventualmente pueden ser usados por los módulos de extensión
 * contribuidos.
 * @param string $path path relativo al directorio del módulo contribuido
 * @param string $modulo nombre del módulo
 */
function leer_archivo_de_texto_auxiliar($path, $modulo){
   // lógica para resolver el path el valor se asigna a $file
   return is_file($file) ? file_get_contents($file) : '';
}
```

#### Pruebas ejecutadas (de momento)

En el método isValidTester inserté un ciclo que recorre las constantes usadas para pasar opciones al método que construye el objeto 'fileinfo' de modo que se puedan comparar sus salidas. Estas son enviadas al array que guarda la información devuelta por finfo_file() para poder usarla o compararla. Y antes de devolver la validación se la envía al formateador de mensajes de depuración (dump) para que sean comparadas. Muestro la invocación y una imagen de la salida obtenida:

```
<?php
// Test de validación de carga de imagen .png foto tomada usando un
// dispositivo android.
use \Biblio2ls\Library\Uploader\FileMimeValidator;
$validador = new FileMimeValidator();
$fileinfo = $_FILES['img_getter'];
$esvalida = $validador->isValidTest($fileinfo);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede observar que la devoluciones obtenidas usando las diferentes constantes no coinciden y que el tipo por defecto  que debiera ser el que debe adoptarse según los cambios no coincide con el declarado por la imagen.

He repetido la prueba para otros tipos y el resultado es muy similar.

#### Modificaciones introducidas

Luego de las primeras pruebas y de reconsiderar el problema se me ocurrió la idea de permitir a quien esté del lado del servidor introducir como parámetro de validación un array de pares clave=>valor, en los que cada clave puede presentar una extensión esperada y cada valor la cadena que se debe obtener cuando la función finfo_file($finfo, $filenm) sea aplicada a un archivo con tal extensión, o un array de valores en caso de que dicha función devuelva diferentes identificaciones al revisar diferentes archivos de un mismo tipo aparente.
Para hacerlo posible agregué un juego de constantes para indicar errores en la verificación de extensiones explícitas y dos atributos para manejo del array citado y usarlo en las validaciones. Adicionalmente, modifiqué varios métodos miembro y agregué dos, así:

**Modificación del constructor de clase**
Se agrega un parámetro opcional de entrada `$custom_constraint=[]` y se escribe la lógica necesaria para dejarlo disponible para ser usado.

```
<?php
// Formato admitido para $custom_constraint
$custom_constraint=[
    'extension' => 'cadena_mime_esperada_como_salida_de_finfo_file',
    'extension' => [
        'cadena_mime_conocida_como_salida_de_finfo_file_para_version_x',
        'otra_cadena_mime_conocida_..._para_otra_version',
        // ...
    // ... otros pares extensión valor esperados
];
```

En las primeras pruebas sólo pienso usar el modelo en que valor sea cadena; pero en caso de que observe salidas diferentes para una misma extensión,  debo usar el modelo aceptando arrays como valores. Presumo las va a haber, dado que la salida: **'JPEG image data, EXIF standar 2.2'** insinúa y adelanta que luego de la coma se presentarán variaciones para la familia .jpg; y de modo análogo para otras extensiones.

**Modificación al método isValid()**
Se agrega un parámetro opcional `$custom_constraint=NULL` para permitir iteración de validaciones sobre familias de archivos sin necedidad de crear nuevas instancias de la clase. Y, a diferencia del constructor el default es NULL para que se pueda resetear o mantener (si viene NULL) el array de restricciones. 
Al método isValidTest() le son aplicados los mismos cambios.

```
<?php
public function isValid(&$fileinfo, $custom_constraint=NULL){
    // Se agrega un llamado a reiniciar los atributos de control
    $this->resetValidation($custom_constraint);
    // ..
    // se agrega verificación de la extensión explícita
    if(!$this->siLaExtensionEsAdmisible($fileinfo) ){ return 0; }
    // ..
    // Se agrega una condición de verificación de tipo mime para
    // tratar el caso en que hay array de restricciones
    if($this->restricted){
        // El tipo de campo declarado debe coincidir con el registro de 
        // extensiones actualizado y estar en las restricciones impuestas
        // @todo: debe cambiarse in_array por un test recursivo si se 
        // admiten arrays de restricciones
        return (in_array($this->file_mime['default_mime_type'], $this->mimesconstraint))  ? 1 : $this->setTipoMimeError($fileinfo, UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
    }elseif($fileinfo['type'] === $mimeasociadoaextension){
         // lo demás sigue igual

}
```

Con estos cambios, y sus asociados, que ya fueron implementados en la clase, espero llevar el problema a su exterior, para hacerla funcional y delegarlos en la decisión de admitir la carga de x tipos de archivo y la preparación de la información de control necesaria para implementarlo.