# insertar imagen y visualizar en php

Tags: php, mysql, imagen, select, insert

Hola buenas estoy intentando insertar una imagen en mi mysql, supuestamente lo inserto bien pero luego lo quiero mostrar y no me muestra la imagen.

Para insertar utilizo esto(no se si esta bien o no):

```
 public function insertar() {
    // Archivo temporal
    $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

    // Tipo de archivo
    $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];

    // Leemos el contenido del archivo temporal en binario.
    $fp = fopen($imagen_temporal, 'r+b');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($imagen_temporal));
    fclose($fp);
    $this->model->insertFotos($_POST["nombre"],$_POST["fecha"],  $data);
    
}
```

Mi archivo para insertar es:

```
<form action="insertar" method="POST" id="formRoles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Fecha de Subida: </label>
  <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Imagen</label>
  <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" accept=".jpg , .png, .gif">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary insert">Insertar</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
</div>
```

y luego para mostrar mis registro utilizo esto:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
  <th scope="col">Fecha de Subida</th>
  <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
  <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
</tr>
 <tbody>
 <?php foreach($data["Fotos"] as $p) :  ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?= $p["Nombre"] ?></td>
  <td><?= $p["FechaSubida"] ?></td>
  <td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($p['imagen']) ?>" alt="<?php echo 
 $p['Nombre']; ?>"></td>
  <td >
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><a class="text-white" href="modificar/<?= 
 $p["idFoto"]?>"><ion-icon class="lead" name="create-outline"></ion-icon></a></button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><a class="text-white" href="eliminar/<?= 
$p["idFoto"]?>"> <ion-icon class="lead" name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></a></button>

  </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

y se ve así:
[image]

las primeras imágenes si se ven por que están directamente subidas al servidor pero desde que lo intento subir desde el proyecto se ve como en la imagen

Comment: Tienes un par de problemas de enfoque del asunto. Antes de responderte quiero saber que deseas hacer con las imágenes: ¿ cómo quieres guardarlas en el servidor ? **Yo no veo que las estés insertando en MySQL** ¿dónde y cómo lo constryues El array `$data["Fotos"]` ?

Comment: Puedes revisar que genera el servidoren el codigo fuente de la pagina para las imagenes con error <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,#####" > fijate si esta vacio o aparece texto o mensajes de error. Son todas las image/ jpg? puede que necesites guardar este dato tambien si pueden ser png u otro formato

Comment: todas son jpg @F.Igor

Comment: @quevedo si quiero insertarlas en el mysql para luego mostrarlas, no ves la consulta por que lo estoy haciendo en mvc y la consulta lo tengo en el modelo este es el controlador

Comment: Lo típico es guardar en la base de datos los paths a los archivos de imágen, y guardar las imágenes dentro de la estructura de directorios, siguiendo algún criterio. ¿Lo haces así o usas **blob**?

Comment: ¿Verificaste qué se guardó en la BD ? Por el código que muestras sospecho que no se guardaron.

Comment: @quevedo lo estoy usando en **blob** no se si eso ayuda jjajaja

Comment: Si. Porque si recuperas las otras imágenes, que presumiblemente se guardaron de la misma manera, y usas el mismo método para mostrarlas, quiere decir que al tratar de guardar las que son subidas no se logró. De modo que el error a corregir está en otra parte. Perdona que demoré en contestar. Me ocupé en otros asuntos.

Comment: No te preocupes @quevedo yo también he estado con otros asuntos y no podía responder al momento 

Comment: La cuestión es que supuestamente la imagen se inserta supuestamente bien, pero cuando quiero mostrarlo no se ve la imagen, yo creo que algo hago mal en la inserción, las otras imágenes si se ven por que esas las inserte manualmente en MySQL @quevedo

Comment: Cuando subes la imagen, el controlador la recibe en $_FILES, si estás usando algún framework este la recogen en algún objeto (no obstante sigue presente en $_FILES), desde allí ha debido ser recogida y guardada en la BD. El código escrito para guardarla es el que debe ser revisado, así: 1. Hacer `var_dump($data);` luego de **fclose** Para asegurar que la lectura funcionó. 2. Revisar el código en el método `$this->model->insertFotos( params...)` que no debe estar pasando $data de modo correcto, pues en la lista se ve que guardó los valores de nombre y fecha.

Comment: alfinal lo de la imagen he podido solucionarlo con esto:  public function insertar()
    {
        $revisar = getimagesize($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($revisar !== false) {
            $image = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
            $imgContenido = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
            $this->model->insertFotos($_POST["nombre"], $_POST["fecha"],  $imgContenido);
        }
    } @quevedo gracias a esto he conseguido que se vea la imagen, ¿usted como lo ve?

Comment: No soy amigo de insertar sin hacer una validación de tipo mime y de no suplantación, y no anidación de código ejecutable, porque es posible que los usuarios que abran la imagen en su navegador reciban un ataque mediante código malicioso. Y, quien sirve la "imagen" es responsable.

Comment: es la primera vez que subo una imagen a un servidor, y es de la única forma que me ha funcionado, pero usted como lo haría @quevedo

Comment: Yo sólo guardo en la BD los paths, los archivos se guardan en carpetas (renombrados) y tengo una clase para hacer validaciones. En esta pregunta que hice hace tiempo [Dificultad al validar tipos mime en php para subir archivos al servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/176888/91033), hay un ejemplo de implementación para esa clase. La pregunta no tiene aún una respuesta satisfactoria y de momento yo implementé **listas blancas** de tipos admitidos para uso personal.

Comment: Todavía no entiendo del todo eso @quevedo (soy algo novato jajaja) espero ir pilándolo poco a poco muchas gracias