# Error al intentar insertar formulario con el campo imagen nulo

Tags: imagen

Tengo un formulario en donde el usuario puede subir una imagen, al principio había colocado el campo en mi BD como no nulo al igual que la función required en el html para que el usuario obligatoriamente llenara el campo type="file" con una imagen. Pero ahora deseo que solo sea opcional subir la imagen, coloque mi campo en la BD como NULL y quité el required del html, sin embargo el condicional me sigue llevando al mensaje de que debo subir una imagen. en la condición he establecido NULL  la variable $extension que es la que determina si hay o no un archivo 'jpg' ó 'png' en el input y realiza la consulta pero igual sigue yéndose a los mensajes de que debo subir una imagen aquí dejo el código:

```
$carpeta="./capturaspagos/"; 
            $nombre= $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
            
            //imagen.algo.jpg
            $temp= explode( '.' ,$nombre);
            $extension= end($temp);
        
            $nombrefinal = time().'.'.$extension;
          
           
            if(($extension=='NULL') ||  ($extension=='jpg') || ($extension=='png') {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpeta.$nombrefinal)){
            $conexion->query("insert into pagos
            (nombre,documento,banco,numero_cuenta,referencia,fecha_pago,fecha_vencimiento,monto,imagen,
            id_usuario,id_plan,id_estatus) values
            ( 
            '".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['apellido']."',
             ".$_POST['documento'].",
            '".$_POST['banco']."',
            ".$_POST['numero_cuenta'].",
            ".$_POST['referencia'].",
            '{$fecha->format('YmdHis')}',
            '{$fecha_venc->format('YmdHis')}',
            ".$_POST['monto'].",
            '$nombrefinal',
            $id,
            $idp,
            '1'
            
          )
            ")or die ($conexion->error);
            header("Location: planes.php?success"); 
        
        }else{
            header("Location: planes.php?error=No se pudo subir la imagen"); 
            }
        }else{
            header("Location: planes.php?error=Por favor subir imagen jpg o png");  
        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Debes verificar el valor recibido en las claves **'error' y 'size'** del array `$_FILES['id_imagen']` en caso de que `$_FILES['id_imagen']['error'] != 0` sabes que la imagen no subió o no subió correctamente y no puedes enviarla a guardar. Empleas 'size' sólo si en error obtienes 0 (OK) para verificar que el tamaño sea mayor que cero y menor que el límite admitido. También debes validar el tipo mime interno (no el declarado en la extensión) para evitar guardar código malicioso y servirlo a tus visitantes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ACTUALIZACION**

1.- Para validar el tipo de archivo te recomiendo utilizar `mime_content_type()` esto verificara el **MIME interno de tu archivo** por lo que si un usuario mal intencionado modifica la extension podrias evitarte problemas al futuro.

2.- Ten en cuenta que tendras 2 consultas diferentes, 1 donde insertas la informacion del archivo, y otra donde no insertas esa informacion, por lo que yo te recomendaria almacenar en una variable tu consulta ejemplo: `$consultaSql = "";` ya que esta cambiara de acuerdo a tus condiciones, te dejo un ejemplo con codigo comentado que te ayudara a resolver tu problema:

```
//VERIFICAS QUE EL ARCHIVO VENGA
if(!empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])){

  //VERIFICAS LOS FORMATOS
   if(mime_content_type($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) =='image/png' || mime_content_type($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])=='image/jpeg'){

     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpeta.$nombrefinal)){
            
      //SI SE REALIZA LA SUBIDA REALIZAS EL INSERT
        
    }else{
      header("Location: planes.php?error=No se pudo subir la imagen"); 
     }

  }else{
   
      //MUESTRAS MENSAJE DE ARCHIVO NO VALIDO
    
   }
} 

else{
 
   //SI NO HAY HAY ARCHIVO SOLO REALIZAS EL INSERT
  
}
```

3.- Repito que la variable  `$consultaSql = "";` cambiara de acuerdo en donde la mandes a llamar, ejemplo: `$consultaSql = "SOY CONSULTA 1";` `$consultaSql = "SOY CONSULTA 2";` y a tu query le pasaras esa variable:

```
$conexion->query($consultaSql)
```

Comment: Hola. En `$_FILES['imagen']['type']` viene el tipo mime asociado a la extensión. Pero se puede poner extensiones arbitrarias a código ejecutable malicioso y se puede insertar código ejecutable dentro de imágenes con tipo declarado correcto. Si no se valida el tipo mime interno, y **que no sea múltiple**, **se tiene una bomba de tiempo** y, si las imágenes que se suben luego son servidas, el sitio queda en cucos y los visitantes pueden ser envenenados. Adicionalmente, puede ser no nulo 'name' y contener un error. revisa [outcontrol constants](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.constants.php)

Comment: @quevedo Tienes toda la razon, estaria genial que brindaras una respuesta sobre como comprobar el **mime-type** de los archivos creo que a mas de 1 le servirá

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación. Desde hace rato tengo una pregunta abierta al respecto: [Dificultad al validar tipos mime en php para subir archivos al servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/176888/91033) **No la he auto-respondido** porque no he logrado una respuesta de fácil implementación para otros. Tengo funcionando, para mí, una solución con listas blancas de tipos para mis aplicaciones web. Pero no es posteable porque le falta generalidad. **Nota:** lo publicado en la pregunta de referencia es suficientemente útil como punto de partida para implementar soluciones personales.

Comment: @quevedo Por cierto vi que en tu POST decias que  **mime_content_type** Estaba obsoleto, pero al entrar a la documentacion OFICIAL no indica nada sobre esto, incluso dice que puedes usarlo en PHP7

Comment: Cierto. Quitaron la marca de obsoleto. Voy a tener que corregir el post. En el momento en que lo escribí estaba declarado, y me sorprendió mucho porque yo lo usaba (aún lo uso) en todas partes. Me queda la preocupación de la no correspondencia con el registro del sistema en **magic** y con algunos valores pasados en $_FILES.

Comment: Hola, @NikolaTesla y Guilermo Quevedo gracias a ambos por responder, lo haré como me explicas Nikola, aunque no entiendo muy bien por qué deben ser dos consultas separadas eso no me queda claro. Y Guillermo es un gran código el que has hecho pero bastante profundo lo vi completo y a pesar de las explicaciones creo que aún no estoy al nivel para entenderlo en su totalidad, pero se ve que pusiste bastante empeño.

Comment: En realidad solo harás 1 consulta, de acuerdo a si se cumple o no una condición, lo que cambiara solo será la variable que te mencionaba anteriormente.

Comment: Hola Nikola gracias, me ha surgido otro inconveniente, esta vez intentando subir varias imágenes al mismo tiempo, cree otro post a ver si puedes ayudarme, gracias de antemano, aquí el link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404025/problema-subiendo-m%c3%baltiples-im%c3%a1genes-a-mi-servidor